# Parse NPM_TOKEN form .npmrc for a particular registry

Tags: bash-scripting

The `.npmrc` file has several entries like this:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=<sometoken>
//my.privateregistry.com/:_authToken=<sometoken>
```

Also there might be completely different entries in `.npmrc`.

How can I parse `<sometoken>` using a bash script for a particular registry by specifying its URL like `registry.npmjs.org` as a param for a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

URLTOSEARCH="$1"
FILENAME="npmrc"

# you have to give an url
# so the search can begin
if [ -z "$URLTOSEARCH" ]; then
        echo "Please enter an url to search."
        exit 1
fi

# first, get the link
# out of the file
while read -r line
do
        # get the url
        EXTRACTEDURL=$(echo "$line" | grep -o '//.*/:' | sed 's/\/:/\//g')

        # get the token
        EXTRACTEDTOKEN=$(echo "$line" | grep -o '_authToken=.*' | sed 's/_authToken=//g')

        if [ "//$URLTOSEARCH/" == "$EXTRACTEDURL" ]; then
                echo "Token found: $EXTRACTEDTOKEN"
        fi
done < "$FILENAME"
```

Comment: using your code, for anyone wanting to extract just a single token from a standard configuration of npm, this is a simple answer: `export NPM_TOKEN=$(cat ~/.npmrc | grep -o '_authToken=.*' | sed 's/_authToken=//g')`

Comment: There's also https://github.com/nice-registry/get-auth-token-from-npmrc but they only return the first token found.